# Set Stylesheet for 4 states of QPushButton

Tags: css, qt, stylesheet, qpushbutton

4 states are: hover, leave, focusIn, focusOut.

What i am doing now is creating a new class (MyButton) and promote QPushButton.

mybutton.cpp:

```
void MyButton::enterEvent(QEvent* e) {
    emit hovered();
}

void MyButton::leaveEvent(QEvent* e) {
    emit leaved();
}

void MyButton::focusInEvent(QFocusEvent* e) {
    emit focused();
}

void MyButton::focusOutEvent(QFocusEvent* e) {
    emit notfocused();
}
```

main.cpp:

```
connect(ui.button, SIGNAL(hovered()), this, SLOT(button_hover()));
connect(ui.button, SIGNAL(focused()), this, SLOT(button_focus()));
connect(ui.button, SIGNAL(leaved()), this, SLOT(button_leave()));
connect(ui.button, SIGNAL(notfocused()), this, SLOT(button_notfocus()));

void MyWindow::button_hover() {
    this->ui.button->setStyleSheet("border-image:url(:/ptd/graphics/button_mouseover.png);");
}

void MyWindow::button_focus() { 
    this->ui.button->setStyleSheet("border-image:url(:/ptd/graphics/button_mouseover.png);");
}

void MyWindow::button_leave() {
    this->ui.button->setStyleSheet("border-image:url(:/ptd/graphics/button_leave.png);");
}

void MyWindow::button_notfocus() {
    this->ui.button->setStyleSheet("border-image:url(:/ptd/graphics/button_leave.png);");
}
```

I think that is too long. What I want to do is:

```
ui.button->setObjectName("Yes");
ui.button->setStyleSheet("QPushButton#Yes{border-image: url(:/ptd/graphics/button_leave.png);}"
                "QPushButton#Yes:hover{border-image: url(:/ptd/graphics/button_mouseover.png);}");
```

which is shorter and we do not have to create a new class. But I just know the state `hover` in this case. How to set for the other 3 states?

Comment: Have you tried the `:focus` state?

Comment: thanks! I have just found it here http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/stylesheet-reference.html#list-of-pseudo-states. It works!